# Parallel Miller-Rabin Prime Test in Haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, primes

I implemented a prime number finder using the Miller-Rabin prime test in Haskell and it seems to be working. You enter a number and it finds the next prime following that number.

I also tried to make it parallel and I'm looking for some advice for how I can speed up the parallel version. Right now it runs much slower than the not parallel version.

Compiled with `ghc -threaded -O2 miller_rabin.hs -o miller_rabin`

Run with `./miller_rabin startnumber npar +RTS -N4` (I have a 4-core processor). `npar` is the parameter for `parBuffer`. If `npar` is 1 then the program runs single-threaded, otherwise is runs with multiple threads.

```
module Main where

import System.Random (StdGen, getStdGen, randomRs)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

main :: IO ()
main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    args <- getArgs 
    let number = read . head $ args :: Integer
        npar = read $ args !! 1 :: Int
    p <- case npar of
            1 -> do putStrLn "Run single thread"
                    return $ find_prime g 20 number
            _ -> do putStrLn "Run multi-threaded"
                    return $ head $ primeList npar g 20 number
    putStrLn . show $ p


miller_rabin :: StdGen -> Int -> Integer -> Bool
miller_rabin g k n = all (not . trial_composite n d r) 
                   $ take k (randomRs (2, n-2) g)    
    where 
        (d, r) = decompose (n-1) 0

trial_composite :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
trial_composite n d r a = let x = fastPow a d n in
    if (x == 1) || (x==n-1) 
    then False
    else all ((/=) (n-1)) $ map (\i -> fastPow a (d*(2^i)) n) [0..r-1]

decompose :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
decompose d r 
    | d `mod` 2 == 0 = decompose (d `div` 2) (r+1)
    | otherwise = (d, r) 


fastPow :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fastPow base 1 m = mod base m
fastPow base pow m | even pow = mod ((fastPow base (div pow 2) m) ^ 2) m
                   | odd  pow = mod ((fastPow base (div (pow-1) 2) m) ^ 2 * base) m


primeList :: Int -> StdGen -> Int -> Integer -> [Integer]
primeList npar g k n = 
    let primes = filter (miller_rabin g k) [m,m+2..]
        primesP = primes `using` parBuffer npar rdeepseq
        m = if even n then n+1 else n
    in primesP

find_prime :: StdGen -> Int -> Integer -> Integer
find_prime g k n 
    | even n    = find_prime g k (n+1)
    | otherwise = case miller_rabin g k n of
                    True  -> n
                    False -> find_prime g k (n+2)
```

Comment: It seems to me like the parallel version is slower because it computes the list elements in parallel, rather than only needing to compute the first list element like the serial version. Make `find_prime` and `primeList` calculate and output the same and `find_prime` shouldn't complete faster anymore.

Comment: @Gurkenglas, I’ll try to do a rewrite, but I thought that the parallel list version would allow the list to be computed quickly and there would only be a penalty at the final chunk.